# Find the first, second, etc. day of week in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a database schema to create reminders very similar to Outlook. You can create Weekly, Monthly and Yearly reminders.

I need to be able to find something like:

```
The first Friday of January
The third Wednesday of every 3 months.
```

Can anyone tell me how to find something like the first, second, third, fourth, etc. date in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: How are you building up the query to search for "the first Friday of January", etc.?  Are you using this DB in an application?  If so, what language?  It might be (probably is) easier to do this in code rather than on the SQL side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datepart` to find out the day of week for the first day of the month:

```
datepart(weekday, '2011-06-01')
```

From that you can calculate the first of any weekday, for example the first Monday (2):

```
(2 + 7 - datepart(weekday, '2011-06-01')) % 7 + 1
```

To get the second monday you just add 7 to that, and so on.

To check if the date is still within the same month you would need the last date of the month, which you can get by subtracting a day from the first day of the next month:

```
datepart(day, dateadd(day, -1, '2011-07-01'))
```

Comment: Beware that the values returned by `datepart` are dependent on the value of `SET DATEFIRST` and can therefore the value for a given day can vary given the user's locale/session settings. See "week and weekday datepart arguments" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: @Ed Harper: Good point. The calculation above doesn't care what the number mean, but you would need to make sure that your application interprets the values correctly.